# Convergence of the k-moving average recursive sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to prove that the sequence $X_{n} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k X_{n-i}}{k}$ is convergent for any $k >= 2$ and initial values $X_1, ... X_k$.

My approach: the characteristic function is given by $f(x) := kx^{k} - x^{k-1} - ... - x - 1$, which can be factorized into $(x-1)(kx^{k-1} + (k-1)x^{k-2} + ... +2x+1)$. Therefore, it suffices to show that all the roots of $g(x) := kx^{k-1} + (k-1)x^{k-2} + ... +2x+1$ lie in the unit disk: $\{z: |z|<1\}$.

This is where I got stuck. I tried applying Rouché's theorem by considering $h(x) = kx^{k-1}$ and $r(x) = (k-1)x^{k-2} + ... + 2x+1$, but could only show that all the roots lie in $\{z: |z| < 2\}$ (we have $|r(x)| < |h(x)|$ for any $|x|=2$).

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe useful: $g(x) = h'(x)$, where $h(x) = \sum_{r = 1}^{k} x^r$.

Comment: Thanks. I think combining your observation and Gauss–Lucas theorem can solve the problem. But I also realize that we can directly apply Rouché's theorem to $f(x)$ and show that all the roots of must lie in $\{z: |z| <= 1\}$ (considering a sequence approaching 1). It is then straightforward to see that all the roots except 1 must strictly lie in the unit disk.